# Maven: Adding classes from war/web-inf/classes as a jar to war/web-inf/lib

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I'm rather new to maven here. I have created a Maven Spring boot project with following structure -

```
..
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenWeb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>MavenWeb</name>
<description>Maven Test Web Application</description>

<dependencies>
 ..
```

As you can see the `packaging` has been set as `war`. As such when the `war` file is generated, my source code's generated `.class files` are generated in the `war/web-inf/classes` folder. Rather than it being generated in classes folder, I'd like to generate it as `jar` file and maintain it in `war/web-inf/lib` folder.

I'm guessing I need to make use of the `maven-jar-plugin` for this.
But I'm not sure how to move the generated jar to `war/web-inf/lib` directory? Is there a simpler alternative to this?

Also how can I restrict the `.class` files from being generated in `war/web-inf/classes` folder?

Would really appreciate some pointers. Many thanks.

Comment: Your dependencies are usually deployed in that lib folder.

Comment: Do you really want a war? If so create a multi module project, one project creates a jar, the other is the war which has a dependency on the jar project.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thanks for the suggestion. But even in this case the war project's `.class` files would still be generated in the classes folder. I'm trying to maintain the `.class` files as a jar in the lib folder so that future code updations can be performed by updating only the jar rather than the whole war. Is there really no other way to handle this?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: I do understand that this is not the convention. But unfortunately for me this is what the higher-ups require. Do let me know if you have some pointers on handling this.

Comment: That simply isn't how maven works. Just put everything you want in a jar in a separate project. What I don't get why even a jar (and it isn't just updating a jar in a library as there might be jsp files or templates as well, and related libs, so just updating 1 library in a war file is a fallacy)

Comment: @M.Deinum: Ours is a huge multi module application(30+ modules) with each module being a microservice. Maintaining 1 dummy war project & another Jar project with src code for each module would be counterproductive. Also most of our modules are backend modules with no ui elements(jsp templates...). Most updations(bug fixes/ feature addons) involve updating only the src code, in which case there is no explicit reason to update the entire war(having sizes of over 800MBs) when u can simply update the src code jar. We have been managing with Ant till now and thought of automating this with maven.

Comment: ehrm. Why would updating the src code jar help? You need the compiled classes? Also patching things like that in production is a bad idea imho but if you want feel free to do so. using multimodule project for this is how maven works, you can probably shoehorn some ant or custom mojo in there to make it work which would confuse the hell out of others who wouldn't understand that customization. And as I also wondered do you really need a war instead of just a jar you can deploy. Also if they are that large there are maybe better options with a separate runner and thin jar option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the `build` section of pom should be -

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenWeb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>MavenWeb</name>
<description>Maven Test Web Application</description>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-jar</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                            <file>
                                ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar
                            </file>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

This would restrict the compiled classes from being generated in classes folder while at the same time generate a thin jar of the compiled classes and add it as `web-inf/lib/MavenWeb-0.0.1.jar`.